# Place content outside DIV in react when toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a toggle in React and it is working when I am pressing the button. What I want to do is to place the courseBody outside of the div with `className="showcourses-field"` because I want the courses to be displayed under the button. When I put `{coursebody}` inside the div it works but it doesn't work when I place it outside the div. How can I place it outside the div?

JS

```
class ShowCourses extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
super();
this.state= {
    showingcourses: false

 }
 }

render(){
    let courseBody;
    let buttonText ="Show More Courses";
    if (!this.state.showingcourses) {
        courseBody = this.props.body;

    } else {
        courseBody = <Course coursename="Food" status="Progress" progress="43%" />
        buttonText = "Hide courses";

    }


    return(
    <div className="showcourses-field">
    <button className="showbutton" onClick={this._toggleCourse.bind(this)}>{buttonText}</button>

    {courseBody}
    </div>




    );


}
    _toggleCourse(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            showingcourses: !this.state.showingcourses
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outside of className="showcourses-field" Div? you know you have to have only one element in return, so just create another Div :

```
<div>
  <div className="showcourses-field">
    <button className="showbutton" onClick={this._toggleCourse.bind(this)}>{buttonText}</button>    
  </div>
  {courseBody}
</div>
```